# How to check size of hidden and system folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

I have a problem with understanding where my disk space goes. I can check with Total commander most of the folders, but it shows only 50 of 121 occupied GB. [image]

With windows explorer I can see also hidden files and folders, but it is not possible to check the size of this folders:

[image]

I also tried [DU](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du) utility, but it also shows nothing [image]

Thereby my question - **how to check size of all types of folder on a windows computer?**

Comment: Your mentioned folder is a shortcut of user folder. Double click on it to redirect the destination of that shortcut.

Comment: It annoyed me a lot that there's effectively no way to check if your disk space is on par with file sizes summed up. On the system disk there are so many files that the MFT takes up considerably large space. There're many soft links and compressed backup files that are smaller on disk than their nominal size. These two effects on mind, you could not figure out the actual space consumption even if you got the sum of every file.

Comment: @Biswa, well. it's says clearly "file folder'. And no, you can't open it. Access denied. Anyway, there are other folders on disk C, which you can neither open nor estimate the size.

Comment: @klm123 Then take ownership of that with `icacls` and `takeown` command.

Comment: You could try using CCleaner's Disk Analyzer to see your disk usage

Comment: @Biswa, i tried the following with no success: https://imgur.com/a/etwzm now I feel like something is wrong with my system ><

Comment: @Bungicasse, oh god, thank you so much! I still don't quite get what were those files, but CCleaner just has cleaned all 72GB of the space I couldn't find. 62GB of which was identified as "System Temporary files" and 10GB as "Windows log files". What is wrong with this OS???